# How to filter array (of objects) inside one document in mongo db based on some condition

Tags: mongodb, collections, document, studio3t

I have the below docs collection structure.
I'm able to filter the documnents with various approaches, but not able to filter the array inside the documents.

```
{
"_id": "",
"employee": {
    "EmployeeAttributeValues": {
        "EmployeeAttributeValue": [
            {.....
            },
            {.....
            },
            {.....
            },
            {.....
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

}

Kindly help me on how to filter the MemberAttributeValue array based on some condition.

Comment: What is the expected outcome?

Comment: i think you need `$filter` see mongodb documentation

Answer (score 0):

you can use $where operator for custom filtering
https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/reference/operator/query/where/

Answer (score 0):

```
db.test.aggregate([
    { $match: {_id: <ID>}},
    { $unwind: '$<ARRAY>'},
    { $match: {'<ARRAY>.a': {$gt: 3}}},
    { $group: {_id: '$_id', list: {$push: '$<ARRAY>.a'}}}
])
```